# Is it possible to trigger 2 hotkeys simultaneously in AHK?

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to simulate mouse movement with my keyboard. I can move in the xy plane one direction at a time but now I need diagonal movement, e.g. holding down shift + w + d moves upright. I would prefer answers that can address the problem of triggering multiple hotkeys simultaneously in general since this is something I would like to implement in other scripts.

```
#NoEnv
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
#SingleInstance Force
#NoTrayIcon
SendMode Input
SetDefaultMouseSpeed, 0

;Variables
taskbar_height := 630
effective_screen_height := A_ScreenHeight - taskbar_height
x_movement := 0.03*A_ScreenWidth
y_movement := 0.05*effective_screen_height

;Mouse
+a::MouseMove, -%x_movement%, 0,, R
+d::MouseMove, %x_movement%, 0,, R
+w::MouseMove, 0, -%y_movement%,, R
+s::MouseMove, 0, %y_movement%,, R
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Standard) AutoHotkey [does not support multi-threading](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Threads.htm), but you can use things like `SetTimer` and other shenanigans for "fake multithreading" (some examples [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=76&t=40294)).

For this specific case, however, it would just be better to have a loop that checks which combination of the critical keys (Shift, w, a, s, and d) are held down and act appropriately based on that.

Note: **[AutoHotkey_H](https://hotkeyit.github.io/v2/)** exists and provides multithreading functionality to vanilla AHK, as well as some other features if you interested in that approach.

Comment: Are there any downsides to using Autohotkey_H?

Comment: It looks like a bit of a hassle to set up, but other than that, I don't think there are any functionality downsides as far as I'm aware